# PostGIS cannot create new feature

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a PostGIS database - using the main user I can create/update new features no worries. I have created a series of new logins and given them all full access to select/insert/update etc all the tables. However when using these new logins I get this error message when inserting new features

```
Could not commit changes to layer tracks

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  permission denied for sequence TRACKS_ID_seq
```

The ID field is of a serial datatype using the line below to assign the value (default from PostGIS).

```
nextval('"TRACKS_ID_seq"'::regclass)
```

Not really sure what else I can try here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got to grant permissions on each of the sequences in addition to the tables, like so:

GRANT ALL ON TABLE [SCHEMA].TRACK_ID_SEQ TO [USER_GROUP];